# How to open and Write specified file in flex web app?

Tags: apache-flex, file, flex4.5

In webApp.
I want to create file in users desktop with some name and I want to write into it How to do this? is it possible using File reference?

Filereference.save() method i tried but it opens dialog box for saving, but i want file to be save in given path without opening dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

From a browser based Flash app; you cannot save a file to the users machine in Flex without user input.  FileREference.save() is the correct approach, but as you discovered it opens a dialog box for user input.

Depending what information you need to store; a local Shared Object may work.  Adobe has some good documentation on using Shared Objects:

- https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Shared+Objects
- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=lsos_5.html
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html
- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=lsos_2.html

Comment: I want something like this `var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);  fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);` `fileStream.writeBytes(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.length);`

Comment: You'll need to use an AIR app then; as those APIs are not available in a browser based web app.